# Get log of IP's connected to apache server

Tags: apache, logging, ip, raspberry-pi

currently I'm developing a small project for a Raspberry Pi. I have set up a server and now i'd like to save some kind of log with all the IP's that have been connected to it at any time.

Honestly I don't know where to start. If you could point me in the right direction it'd be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache access logs are stored in /var/log/httpd
you can retrieve the clients IPs with this regex:

```
grep -o '^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' access_log
```